# How to fix range of axis in plot without specifying a number

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing a polar plot with matplotlib and I have almost everything ready by now. The problem is that I have several datafiles and it would be convenient to get the axis limits automatically instead of me having to set it each time. So the code is like this

```
def rose_diagram(x, y, N):
# Compute pie slices
theta = 2 * np.pi * x / N
radii = y 
width = np.pi / 24     

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0, color=colors, alpha=0.9)

# Format x axis
ax.set_xticks((np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,24,endpoint=False)))
ax.set_xticklabels([xlabels])

# Format y axis
max_r = y.max() + ((y.max()-y.min())/10)
ax.set_yticks((0,max_r/2,max_r))
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[0].set_visible(False)

# Add nighttime
night_theta = 55*np.pi/180
night_width = 145*np.pi/180
ax.bar(night_theta,max_r,night_width, bottom=0.0, color='gray', alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that when I add the "nighttime the axis rescales and i get this graph
[polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7yEG.png)

and what I want is that the nighttimebar goes until the end of the polar plot instead of it increasing the size of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you can add `ylim = ax.get_ylim()` after you make your non-nighttime bars. This saves the default radial axis limits that result from just drawing the bars. Then at the end, add `ax.set_ylim(ylim)` to revert to those saved axis limits (that were there before you added nighttime).